# Renewed US visa - travelling to a different state

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, b1-b2-visas

I have a US b1/b2 visa, I renewed it in 2017, and it that expire in September this year. I want to use it now. I was just wondering because I had been told not to travel to my expected state now, since I did not pick the state while renewing the visa.

Please I need your candid advice, I got the visa the first time for attending a printing show, whereas the show is not available now and I just want to go on vacation to visit a friend in another state.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is rather unclear, but you seem to be saying that you have a multiple-entry B-1/B-2 visa that was issued for the purpose of attending a printing show and asking whether you can use it for the entirely different purpose of visiting a friend in a different state.  The answer to that question is *yes, you can.*

It is in the nature of multiple-entry visas that people may use them for different purposes from the one put forth in the visa application.  The subsequent purpose must of course be permissible under that type of visa.  Since a B-1/B-2 visa covers visitors for business or for pleasure, your visiting a friend is covered.

The fact that your subsequent visit is in a different state is of no consequence whatsoever.  US immigration law does not operate differently in different states.

As always, the standard advice applies: that you can use the visa for this trip does not guarantee your admission to the US.  When you arrive, you will have to convince the immigration officer that you meet the requirements to be admitted as a visitor.